# Button to open webview

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I make a button open webview? I have WebView already implementet. When I push the RaisedButton, it should open a webview. I tried it but didn't get it to work.

Here's the code:

```
Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: inform,
              child: Text('Montag'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Dienstag'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Mittwoch'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Donnerstag'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Freitag'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: Where is the webview?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi thats the point - I don't know how to make the button open it. With "I have WebView already implementet" I meant that I importet it and wrote it im the pubspec file. I also used it down in the code.

Comment: What's the plugin that you're using?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi webview_flutter: 0.3.22

Comment: I think you should post the code for the `inform` function as we don't see any logic in the code to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `Navigator.push` and pass `url` 
code snippet

```
inform() {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => YourWebView('https://flutter.dev')));
  }
  
class YourWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  String url;
  YourWebView(this.url);

  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter WebView example'),
        ),
        body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return WebView(
            initialUrl: url,
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class YourWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  String url;
  YourWebView(this.url);

  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter WebView example'),
        ),
        body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return WebView(
            initialUrl: url,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller.complete(webViewController);
            },
            navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
              if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
                print('blocking navigation to $request}');
                return NavigationDecision.prevent;
              }
              print('allowing navigation to $request');
              return NavigationDecision.navigate;
            },
            onPageStarted: (String url) {
              print('Page started loading: $url');
            },
            onPageFinished: (String url) {
              print('Page finished loading: $url');
            },
            gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
          );
        }));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  inform() {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => YourWebView('https://flutter.dev')));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: inform,
                child: Text('Montag'),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Dienstag'),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Mittwoch'),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Donnerstag'),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Freitag'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helped me out! But now I've tried to implement the BottomNavigationBar from here: [https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html]. Now I get this Error:  `lib/main.dart:314:24: Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'vpmontag'.
            onPressed: vpmontag,
                       ^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:318:24: Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'vpdienstag'.
            onPressed: vpdienstag,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^
` Why?

Comment: Need to reproduce. Could you post your reproduce code to a new question? thanks.

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62992799/implement-bottomnavigationbar

Answer (score 0):

The way I implemented it, was to push a new widget on to the stack, which had the webview:

```
WebView(
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    initialUrl: "https://yourURL.com",
    onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
        _controller.complete(webViewController);
    },
),
```

Comment: But how can I do it with the button? Sorry I'm new at flutter and dart.